# How to auto-off screen and close noisy apps on iPhone after 10 minutes of inactivity at night?

Tags: iphone, ios, display, sleep-wake

##### Background

My mom enjoys TikTok on her iPhone at night. She often unknowingly falls asleep with it on, playing TikTok all night (I guess TikTok blocks the screen auto-off while running), shortening battery life and reducing her sleep quality. Sometimes worse, the screen stays still and lit all night, which I worry could cause the screen burn-in. It's an iPhone 14 Pro Max if it's relevant.

##### Question

Is there a method (including via external apps) to automatically turn off the iPhone’s screen and close all background apps (at least TikTok playing in the background, making sound, if not all) if:
A) The time is between midnight and 7:00 AM
**AND** B) There’s been no activity/input for over 10 minutes.

Not necessary but nicer to have: a free method.